# Reverse Order of a Nested Dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary, reverse

I have a two-layered dictionary and would like a simple command or function (if possible) to reverse the order of the dictionary, but only the outer layer, not the inner. For instance, if my dictionary were as follows:

```
{'dictA': {'key_1': 'value_1'}, 'dictB': {'key_2': 'value_2'}, 'dictC': {'key_3', 'value_3'}}
```

and I wanted to instead make it the following:

```
{'dictC': {'key_3', 'value_3'}, 'dictB': {'key_2': 'value_2'}, 'dictA': {'key_1': 'value_1'}}
```

How would I do this? I have tried methods like `invertdict()` and inv_map = `{v: k for k, v in my_map.items()}`, but I had no success with either.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse the items:

```
>>> dict(reversed(d.items()))
{'dictC': {'value_3', 'key_3'}, 'dictB': {'key_2': 'value_2'}, 'dictA': {'key_1': 'value_1'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code would do the trick:

`dict(reversed(current_dct.items()))`

Comment: Which version of Python is this? I am using 3.6. In 3.6, I didn't think dictionary objects are reversible and when I checked it gives me this error :

`TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not reversible`

Answer (score 0):

If your using Python 3.6 or lower, dictionary order is not maintained or guaranteed. What you could do is use a [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and apply [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) to reverse the dictionary:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = {'dictA': {'key_1': 'value_1'}, 'dictB': {'key_2': 'value_2'}, 'dictC': {'key_3', 'value_3'}}
>>> OrderedDict(reversed(list(d.items())))
OrderedDict([('dictC', {'value_3', 'key_3'}), ('dictB', {'key_2': 'value_2'}), ('dictA', {'key_1': 'value_1'})])
```

`OrderedDict()` is a subclass of `dict`, so it works like a normal dictionary.

However, if you are using a newer version of Python, then dictionary insertion order is maintained. So you could just do the following:

```
>>> dict(reversed(list(d.items())))
{'dictC': {'value_3', 'key_3'}, 'dictB': {'key_2': 'value_2'}, 'dictA': {'key_1': 'value_1'}}
```

**Note:** For safety reasons, its probably better to cast `list()` to `d.items`, since older versions pre Python 3.8 don't allow reversing of type `dict_items`. You will raise a `TypeError: 'dict_items' is not reversible` error otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions that implement `reversed` don't seem to work in older versions of Python i.e. pre 3.8. This solution should work in Python 3.x

**Code**

```
so_dict = {'dictA': {'key_1': 'value_1'}, 'dictB': {'key_2': 'value_2'}, 'dictC': {'key_3', 'value_3'}}

{k: v for k, v in sorted(list(so_dict.items()), key=lambda x:x[0].lower(), reverse=True)}
```

**Output**

```
{'dictC': {'key_3', 'value_3'},
 'dictB': {'key_2': 'value_2'},
 'dictA': {'key_1': 'value_1'}}
```